# Date Signed Field Font Issue

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending Documents to DocuSign for Signing using API version 2. On these documents, I have added "Date Signed tab" at many places to display Date at the time of signing. I am setting Font as "Times New Roman" with Font Size as "11" as entire document is in this font with the same font size. However, During reviewing/signing process as well as on completion documents, Font of the Date seems to be different and it clearly stands out from the other text in the document.

Why DocuSign is behaving in this manner? Is there any other setting through API that I am missing?

Comment: This might be an account setting for allowing different fonts.  I'll look into this and see if I can locate it...

Comment: After testing this I believe this is a bug, the font looks ok when the envelope is sent through the DocuSign Console, but this issue appears when sent through the REST API.  I've logged a bug with DocuSign, will post here once I hear back...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with DocuSign's REST API.  I've logged a bug with them, will post here once we hear back.

Comment: This bug is scheduled to be fixed for the August release, which usually comes out the first week of the month...